# Is it possible to access data in Google Drive using a regular account without user authentication?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a web application which have a document upload/download feature. I'd like to use Google Drive for storing these documents. Is it possible to have the web app own a regular Google  account but that doesn't require user's consent for the app to access the Drive? Or is this only possible using a Service account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. see stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/… for a set of steps to do this. "own" isn't quite the correct term, "access" would be better.

Comment: This requires consent by having the user go to the playground.

Comment: Wrong. It requires the app developer giving consent for the app to access the app developer's account. From the question "Is it possible to have the web app own a regular Google account"